# How to get common values between two columns in R?

Tags: r

Dataframe as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A,B,C","A,D","B,C,E","C,E,G"),
                 y = c("A","D","A",NA),
                 MyAim = c("A","D","",""))

      x    y MyAim
1 A,B,C    A     A
2   A,D    D     D
3 B,C,E    A      
4 C,E,G <NA>
```

I want to get common values between x and y columns in a new one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mapply` :

```
df$Z <- mapply(function(x, y) {
            temp <- intersect(x, y)
            if(length(temp)) temp else ""
        }, strsplit(df$x, ","), df$y)

df
#      x    y Z
#1 A,B,C    A A
#2   A,D    D D
#3 B,C,E    A  
#4 C,E,G <NA>
```

---

If there are multiple values in `y`, we can split the string in `y` and return a comma-separated value.

```
df$Z <- mapply(function(x, y) {
     temp <- intersect(x, y)
     if(length(temp)) toString(temp) else ""
     }, strsplit(df$x, ","), strsplit(df$y, ","))
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A,B,C","A,D","B,C,E","C,E,G"),
                 y = c("A","D","A",NA),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: What should we do if Z column has multiple common values? or e.g. df$y[1] is A,B @Ronak

Comment: @nerdakgul spit `y` as well and get comma-separated value from the function. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`strsplit` could easily be used in an `apply` which coerces to character, try

```
df <- transform(df, MyAim=apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  s <- el(strsplit(x[1], ","))
  s[match(x[2], s)]
  }))
df
# x    y MyAim
# 1 A,B,C    A     A
# 2   A,D    D     D
# 3 B,C,E    A  <NA>
# 4 C,E,G <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: `?el` - new function of the day for me.

Answer (score 0):

If x is character, then the following is one of many ways to do this:

```
intersect(unlist(strsplit(df$x, split=",")), df$y)
```

If x is not a character, then `strsplit` will crash, so the following is required:

```
intersect(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$x), split=",")), df$y)
```

And to add this to the data frame,

```
myAim <- intersect(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$x), split=",")), df$y)
df$myAim <- c(myAim, rep(NA, nrow(df)-length(myAim)))
df
      x    y myAim
1 A,B,C    A     A
2   A,D    D     D
3 B,C,E    A  <NA>
4 C,E,G <NA>  <NA>
```

---

Note:
If `y` contained values like in `x`, then the length of `myAim` may be higher than the number of rows of the data frame. In that situation, adding the result to the data frame may not seem appropriate.